# CSV file writing issue android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

i am developing a app in which i need to retrieve data from sqlite database using different ids, i have done much work but my problem is when i make CSV file i get also columns names as well with every id 
Like i am get CSV file in this type

[image: please open this link to see picture]

I am using this code

```
    public void getData() {


    File dbFile = getDatabasePath("formantime.db");
    SQLITEDBTABLE dbhelper = new SQLITEDBTABLE(getApplicationContext());
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    file = new File(exportDir, "FTSData.csv");

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

        for (String ids : TimeEntryListViewAdapter.emailintArrayList) {


            curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RecordsTable WHERE RecordId ='" + ids + "'", null);
            csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
            if (curCSV.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //Which column you want to exprort

                    String[] arrStr = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2), curCSV.getString(3),
                            curCSV.getString(4), curCSV.getString(5), curCSV.getString(6)};
                    csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);

                } while (curCSV.moveToNext());


            }
            curCSV.close();
        }

        csvWrite.close();
    } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }


    Uri u1 = null;
    u1 = Uri.fromFile(file);


    String[] emails;
    ArrayList<String> mails = EmailReportsAdapter.emailsList;
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/richtext");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mails.toArray(new String[mails.size()]));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Sending mail.."));

    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

        Toast.makeText(EmailReports.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    TimeEntryListViewAdapter.emailintArrayList.clear();

}
```

}

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you write the column names each time a new id was found.

I assumed here you might want to fetch columnnames dynamically so i fetched a dummy entry.

`curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RecordsTable WHERE RecordId ='1'", null);`

Try like this.

```
try {
             file.createNewFile();
             CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
             SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

             /* fetch a dummy entry */
             curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RecordsTable WHERE RecordId ='1'", null);

             csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames()); // write column names only once.

             for (String ids : TimeEntryListViewAdapter.emailintArrayList) {

                curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM RecordsTable WHERE RecordId ='" + ids + "'", null);

                 if (curCSV.moveToFirst()) {
                     do {
                         //Which column you want to exprort

                         String[] arrStr = {curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2), curCSV.getString(3),
                                 curCSV.getString(4), curCSV.getString(5), curCSV.getString(6)};
                         csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);

                     } while (curCSV.moveToNext());


                 }
                 curCSV.close();
             }

             csvWrite.close();
         } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
             Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
         }
```

Comment: selecting single id data is not a problem but i want to get multiple data using ids that is why i am using loop here as you can see above the query

Comment: This method will print data against id 1 and then print data against ids which are coming from loop? if i am wrong please correct me thanks :)

Comment: By using `curCSV = ` you assign or reassign value to this object. So by using it a second time you overwrite previous data

Comment: No by using this code it is not writing any data to file :(

Comment: no not any error when i get file for email using intent there is no data in the file

Comment: could you log what data `curCSV` has?

Comment: when i removed the dummy data query no it is working and giving me data as i was already getting

Comment: Ok i try to log it